# What is the convention for optional dependency injection via properties?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, dependencies, code-injection, convention

What is the convention when I have dependencies which are optional, like for example logging ?
I want to have them injected by properties. And what after when nobody set it? Check for null every time ? Or get a fake logger which does nothing ? 
1.The problem is not related only for logging.
2. I am asking for convention when injecting via properties.

Comment: Your design is flawed. Dependencies should never be "optional". Can you provide a more solid use case for your scenario?

Comment: That's interesting. So how should look like logger when I don't want to log when running unit tests? I use log4net

Comment: What if I write library which includes logging. As I read, convention is to inject it via constructor, but I don't want user to have it necessary, that's why I inject it via properties. Logging is addition, not main functionality. Why can't be optional ?

Comment: How about having a flag whether to log or not?

Comment: Imran, checking that flag every time when I want to use it this object is the same as checking for null

Comment: If Unit Testing is your concern with this.. you should be aware that Mocking frameworks exist for this very purpose..

Comment: Yeah I know it. But what if someone forget to inject that logger mock ? Will get null reference exception. My job is to prevent situations like this, am I not right?

Comment: I think it would be better to centralize all the logging calls to a method say "Log(...)" and you can do the stuff like null check or flag check like IsLoggingRequired in this method.

Comment: I made an extension method for method "Log" which checked for null, but now I just made class FakeLogger which does nothing. It implements ILog interface. It's working but don't know if it's best solution

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17613795/logging-and-dependency-injection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Property injection is typically used when you can generally rely on a default implementation but want the option of injecting an alternative.

In your example, you might create a DefaultLogger that the class uses unless someone passes in an alternative via a property.

I think there should always be an instance of something, a 'null object' maybe. Checking for null doesn't feel right.

Also, have you considered decoration? Logging is a great example of how decoration can add extra, optional, features.