# IoC and binding to interfaces

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

Forgive a genuine but n00b level query, please. I'm doing a new project and starting to bake in the IoC aspect of it. It's the first I've worked on where I was in charge of building up the framework so I'm cutting my teeth with IoC somewhat. I'm taking a hearty recommendation to use Ninject. Cool.

But as I sit down to create my first class that will rely on constructor injection, it strikes me - I still need to use all of these quite custom/3rd party interfaces in the constructors. So How is it that my code is less coupled to log4net if my classes all take a log4net ILog instance in their constructor? I still need a using statement for log4net in each file that wants to log anything.

I thought *that* was the point - abstraction and de-coupling of your multitudes of classes, and pushing all of the dependencies into one class. It seems to me that every class that wants to log anything is still quite bound to log4net, and to change log4net out for another logger would be tedious all the same. how is this a win?

I'm sure I'm missing something, so help me out? Am I meant to create my own interfaces everywhere I wanted to be truly decoupled and then add adapters for the implementations or something? Only then would it seem to be we've pushed all the dependencies to one area.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5646820/logger-wrapper-best-practice

Comment: Consider moving your cross-cutting concerns (logging) into a decorator class that you then register with Ninject. And use proxy classes for your third party dependencies.

Comment: Yes, that SO discussion is the sort of thing I was expecting. Sorry, it didn't come up in my search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use IOC, you inject the interfaces into your class, not the implementation, so that is ok. To get around your specific problem, try looking at the common logging framework (http://netcommon.sourceforge.net/) which itself is a wrapper for log4net or a multitude of other logging frameworks.

This couples you to the common logging framework, but it is very widely used, stable and abstracts the specific of logging without you having to do any of that yourself.

When I have used this in the past, I use a post build script to bring the log4net assemblies into the output directory, so the binding happens at runtime only. For testing purposes and as far as your code is concerned, you are talking to the common logging framework via the public interface provided.

Comment: Right, that's the idea, and that addresses the specific logging issue. But it's a more general question; logging was just one example. To the extent I reach into my container for interfaces that are themselves bound to specific libraries, I'm no less bound than I was in the classes who rely on those interfaces inside their constructors. The very general case itself doesn't *feel* all that useful to me yet.

Comment: Well, you are right - you can write your own interface and your own wrapper class, I mean they have to come from somewhere right? What I was suggesting is looking for re-usable interfaces/wrappers that already have all that code done already. You still aren't binding to any real usable implementations of your injected services which means they can easily be swapped out later. It really depends on the libs you want to use and how far you want to take IOC. IMHO, the further you take it - the more robust your code will become. It is lots of work, so if some else has done it already... :)

Comment: Oh, also meant to say that you can also register dependencies through configuration. I use unity rather than ninject, but the principles are the same - you can further decouple your own interfaces / wrappers by configuring your IOC container via  a loose file such as the app.config or a specific config file (IOC implementation dependant of course).

Comment: The key point about the binding is that while you are bound to a concrete implementation, those bindings are all defined in a single location (composition root), so if you need to swap or change them in the future, you do it in one place. Also, when you start to unit test and need to mock implementations, you'll see it's much easier when bound to the interface.

Comment: But that's my point - "just do it in one place" is what is attractive about the whole thing, but it's a false claim - if I in ject instances of log4net's ILog interface into every class that needs to log anything, how many changes is that when I decide to scrap log4net and use another logger? Very, very many. Where's the win?

Comment: @user2403744 I think that what ColinYoung is saying is that if all the bindings are done in one place - the composition root(regardless of where the interfaces and implementations live), you only have to modify the composition root to change the dependencies required by the program. This doesn't not make the claim that the interfaces are decoupled from the implementation - as I said earlier - you need to either do that yourself or find a library where it has been done for you. DI/IOC doesn't give you all that independence free of charge!

Comment: Point taken. I guess you just see a lot of examples that fall well short of the mark if you really want decoupling throughout your system. The mere existence of a root doesn't free you from an implementation at all; you still need put some facades in place to stabilize your consuming classes.

Comment: That's it, you got it - just don't try to reinvent the wheel, if someone has done the hard work of creating the facades then you can save a lot of time using them :) good luck and don't forget to mark this post as your accepted answer if you are satisfied with the explanation given.

Answer (score 0):

I know what are you talking about! you are going to make a kind of generalization to reduce code duplication(I'm hopping). as you are using .net framework, I have to say that it does not support for aspect oriented programming by default to let you behave different in every situation. for example take a look at this piece of code:

```
public class BlogService : IBlogService
    {
        private readonly IBlogRepository _blogRepository;
        private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        public BlogService(
            IBlogRepository blogRepository,
            IUnitOfWork unitOfWork,
            ILogger logger)
        {
            _blogRepository = blogRepository;
            _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
            _logger = logger;
        }

   public GetAllBlogPostResponse GetAllBlogPost(GetAllBlogPostRequest request)
        {
            var response = new GetAllBlogPostResponse();
            try
            {
                var blogPosts = _blogRepository.GetAll();
                if (blogPosts != null)
                {
                    response.BlogPostViewModel = blogPosts.ConvertToPostListViewModel();
                    response.Success = true;
                    response.MessageType = MessageType.Success;
                    response.Message =       ServiceMessages.GeneralServiceSuccessMessageOnRetrieveInformation;
                    _logger.Log(string.Format(response.Message));
                }
                else
                {
                    response.MessageType = MessageType.Info;
                    response.Message = ServiceMessages.GeneralServiceAlarmMessageOnRetrieveInformation;
                    _logger.Log(string.Format(response.Message));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                response.Success = false;
                response.Message = ServiceMessages.GeneralServiceAlarmMessageOnRetrieveInformation;
                _logger.Log(string.Format(response.Message));
                _logger.Log(exception.Message);
            }
            return response;
        }
```

I have injected IBlogRepository, IUnitOfWrork and ILogger(Log4net) in every service class of my application. rather than that I have similar response and generic message in every catch statement. once I wanted to make a kinds of generalization and not to re-implement the similar code in every service class but you making generalization in such a condition will be more cost effective and difficult. although it's so important to not duplicate the code in some situations, for example I have this BaseController and derive all of my controller from that:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ICookieStorageService _cookieStorageService;
        private readonly ILanguageService _languageService;

        public BaseController(ICookieStorageService cookieStorageService,ILanguageService languageService)
        {
            _cookieStorageService = cookieStorageService;
            _languageService = languageService;
        }
    }
```

so I don't need to create the cookieStorageService and languageService in my controllers each time as I have implemented it in for once.