# What is better for logging: follow good programming practices and inject log in all classes, or use a singleton logger?

Tags: logging, dependency-injection, singleton

I have a project with lots of classes. Before I used a singleton logger, but then I had to change the way logging was done. In this way I had to change all log calls in lots of places. Then I tried using the advise of injecting log. Lots of people say singletons are evil and its better to inject logs, because it is a good programming practice to inject dependencies. Then I realized how difficult and troublesome it is to inject log in every class of my project. I also realized that is more error prone for begginers which will do maintenance in the project, because they understand better the use of a singleton than the dependency injection.

So, in this specific case, taking into consideration the team with beginners, am I doing right to inject logs? Or should I stick to the singleton?

Comment: There is no need to inject the log into every class. You probably want to wrap the logging resource into one controller class and inject the LogService interface only once in that controller class. Then use the LogController when needed elsewhere. I prefer loose coupling. If I need to write to a log I shouldn't care how it is implemented or if it is logging to a database or event log. By the way, your DI container can use a singleton instance of your logger, this is very common.

Comment: so, if i understood it right, i could replace my singleton to a DI container, which will hold the singleton instance of the logger. Isnt the DI container a singleton itself?

Comment: Yes, instances are usually created in the container as a singletons, but this is not a requirement of di. I added an answer with a static controller based approach.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9915056/264697

Comment: Informative: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5646820/logger-wrapper-best-practice

Comment: very informative posts, thanks steven. So its better for all my classes to have an interface to inject the log, instead of just using a singleton logger?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to envision a controller that can be accessed statically such as `LoggingController.Logerror()`.

```
public static class LoggingController
{
    //Create a singleton of the logger
    private static readonly ILoggingService service=MyApplication.Core.Factory.AppServiceFactory.Instance.Create<ILoggingService>();

    public static void LogWarning(string logStr)
    {
        LoggingService srv = new LoggingService(service);
        srv.LogWarning(logStr);
    }

    public static void LogInfo(string logStr)
    {
        LoggingService srv = new LoggingService(service);
        srv.LogInfo(logStr);
    }

    public static void LogError(string logStr)
    {
        LoggingService srv = new LoggingService(service);
        srv.LogError(logStr);
    }   
}
```