# Implementation and usage of logger wrapper for Serilog

Tags: c#, .net, logging, serilog

This question is related to [Steven](https://stackoverflow.com/users/264697/steven)’s answer - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5646876/4908919). He proposed a very good logger wrapper. I will paste his code below:

```
public interface ILogger
{
    void Log(LogEntry entry);
}

public static class LoggerExtensions
{
    public static void Log(this ILogger logger, string message)
    {
        logger.Log(new LogEntry(LoggingEventType.Information,
            message, null));
    }

    public static void Log(this ILogger logger, Exception exception)
    {
        logger.Log(new LogEntry(LoggingEventType.Error, 
            exception.Message, exception));
    }

    // More methods here.
}
```

So, my question is **what is the proper way to create implementation that proxies to Serilog**?

Note: this question is related to [this question about log4net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32342310/implementation-and-usage-of-logger-wrapper/32342484#32342484) but now specific to Serilog.

Comment: why are you referring to yourself? :D it's a circular reference

Comment: @Sherlock since this is just a copy of an identical question (asked by someone else) about log4net. I just needed this information to be publicly documented and stackoverflow is very useful for this.

Comment: Note, passing `exception.Message` through as the message is suboptimal with Serilog; instead, if you have to deal with events without a message of their own, use a constant [message template](https://messagetemplates.org) like `{ExceptionMessage}` and parameterize it with `exception.Message`. This avoids attempting to parse the message as a template, and won't pollute the internal message template cache. Cheers!

Comment: Hi Nick, feel free to update my answer or add your own.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> So, my question is what is the proper way to create implementation that proxies to Serilog?

you should create something like:

```
public class SerilogAdapter : ILogger
{
    private readonly Serilog.ILogger m_Adaptee;

    public SerilogAdapter(Serilog.ILogger adaptee)
    {
        m_Adaptee = adaptee;
    }

    public void Log(LogEntry entry)
    {
        if (entry.Severity == LoggingEventType.Debug)
            m_Adaptee.Debug(entry.Exception, entry.Message);
        if (entry.Severity == LoggingEventType.Information)
            m_Adaptee.Information(entry.Exception, entry.Message);
        else if (entry.Severity == LoggingEventType.Warning)
            m_Adaptee.Warning(entry.Message, entry.Exception);
        else if (entry.Severity == LoggingEventType.Error)
            m_Adaptee.Error(entry.Message, entry.Exception);
        else
            m_Adaptee.Fatal(entry.Message, entry.Exception);
    }
}
```

> Does that mean that every class that will log sth (so basically every), should have ILogger in its constructor?

As I understand from Stevens answer: Yes, you should do this.

> what is the best way to use it later in the code?

If you are using a DI container, then just use the DI container to map `ILogger` to `SerilogAdapter`. You also need to register `Serilog.ILogger`, or just give an instance of Serilog logger to the DI container to inject it to the SerilogAdapter constructor.

If you don't use a DI container, i.e., you use [Pure DI](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di/), then you do something like this:

```
Serilog.ILogger log = Serilog.Log.Logger.ForContext("MyClass");

ILogger logging_adapter = new SerilogAdapter(log);

var myobject = new MyClass(other_dependencies_here, logging_adapter);
```

Comment: How should this be used with the current dependency injection used in Core 2.2?  Within ConfigureServices I have:   services.AddSingleton<ILogger, SerilogAdapter>();  Problem is, this throws the following error:   InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Serilog.ILogger' while attempting to activate 'MyProject.Logging.Adapters.SerilogAdapter'

Comment: @RichieMN you've probably solved this issue by now but, just to document it here - just add `services.AddSingleton(Serilog.Log.Logger);` too.

Comment: Thank you for the response!

Comment: Will the SerilogAdapter.Log pickup the CallerMember, LineNumber etc values from the calling class or will it always populate as SerilogAdapter class as the initiator ? for eg - if Class A is writing log by calling logging_adapter.log on line 10, then will the Serilog log message with Callermember as ClassA or SerilogAdapter?

Comment: Am I missing something or am I correct in my understanding this will negate the structured logging that Serilog supports?

Comment: Structured logging is not part of the abstraction as specified here. You should design the abstraction so it suits your application.