# Resolve Microsoft.Extensions.Logging ILogger instead of ILogger<T> with Autofac and SeriLog

Tags: logging, dependency-injection, autofac, serilog

When working with Microsoft.Extensions.Logging, normally one registers an `ILoggerfactory` and map between the logger implementation and `ILogger<>`.

I was looking for a way to inject the non-generic `ILogger` and letting the IoC-Container (in this case Autofac) generate the typed `ILogger<>` with the class is getting injected to.

In this article https://blog.rsuter.com/logging-with-ilogger-recommendations-and-best-practices/ it is said:

> Prefer injecting the `ILogger` interface and if necessary the `ILogger<T>` interface. Ideally, your class’ constructor requests an ILogger and the IoC framework creates an instance of an `ILogger<T>` where `T` is the requesting class.

And I agree with it, I would like to be able to inject just an ILogger and get the correct contextual instance.

The autofac serilog integration (https://github.com/nblumhardt/autofac-serilog-integration) does something like this but for Serilog.

> This library configures Autofac to automatically configure the correct contextual logger for each class into which an `ILogger` is injected.

So is there a way to get this working with `Autofac`, `SeriLog` and `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging`?

I have tried a bit without a lot of effort.

Steven proposed [something cool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39499229/implementation-and-usage-of-logger-wrapper-for-serilog/39499230#39499230) which I may get working by using the above autofac serilog integration and injecting the Serilog Logger into my custom abstraction, but this way I would lose the ability for structured logging, etc.

It would be nice if someone could give some guidance.

Comment: Could you share what have you tried so far ?