# I'm implementing similar wrapper like this. But, my question is how do I add configuration in appsettings.json to this

Tags: wrapper, serilog

Refer to this thread
[Implementation and usage of logger wrapper for Serilog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39499229/implementation-and-usage-of-logger-wrapper-for-serilog/39499230#39499230?newreg=48cccaf339794acda019bf81094b0448)

In the Program.cs file in .NET 6

IConfiguration conf = (new ConfigurationBuilder().SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
.Build());

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(options);
builder.Services.AddScoped();

Comment: Thanks Kofi for the super fast response. But, I'm still lost. Here's my code.

Answer (score 0):

To add configuration to your .NET Core application, you can use the ConfigurationBuilder class and read the values from the appsettings.json file.

Here's an example of how to do this:

Create a new instance of ConfigurationBuilder:

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
Build the configuration object:

IConfigurationRoot configuration = builder.Build();
```

Use the GetValue method to read the configuration value:

```
var value = configuration.GetValue<string>("YourConfigKey");
```

So, for example, if you have a setting called WrapperApiKey, your appsettings.json file could look like this:

```
{
  "WrapperApiKey": "your_api_key_here"
}
And you could read the value in your code like this:

var apiKey = configuration.GetValue<string>("WrapperApiKey");
```

Make sure to replace "YourConfigKey" with the actual key you want to read from the appsettings.json file.