# During constructor injection can the Unity DI Container recognize the type that is being constructed, and use it when resolving a reference?

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, unity-container

I want to inject a `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging` logger into the constructor of a class using the Unity DI container:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace LoggingExample
{    
    public class MyClass
    {
        private readonly ILogger<MyClass> _logger;

        public MyClass(ILogger<MyClass> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public void DoSomething()
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Doing something.");
        }
    }
}
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41244169/216440) Stackoverflow answer suggests it's a bad idea to inject `ILogger<T>` as it's too specific.  Instead, the answer suggests injecting the non-generic base type, `ILogger`, which is simpler, easier to test and less error prone (from copy and paste errors mainly, I would guess).

In the class above we'd want to change the data type of the constructor parameter:

```
        public MyClass(ILogger logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }
```

Then we'd need some way of resolving `ILogger` into `Logger<MyClass>` for this class, or `Logger<T>` in the more general case for any class, where `T` represents the class being injected into.

This is done in that Stackoverflow answer using the Simple Injector DI container and conditional registration:

```
container.RegisterConditional(
    typeof(ILogger),
    c => typeof(Logger<>).MakeGenericType(c.Consumer.ImplementationType),
    Lifestyle.Singleton,
    _ => true);
```

Is conditional registration possible in Unity?  is there any other way Unity could recognize the class it's injecting `ILogger` into and resolve the reference to inject a `Logger<T>` object (where `T` is the class being injected into)?

Comment: You could just cast it back to `Logger<MyClass>` in your constructor.

Comment: @howcheng: Unity will still be resolving `ILogger` to `Logger<T>` when it is injecting `ILogger` objects into the constructor, won't it?  How will Unity know to use the appropriate type parameter when resolving `ILogger` if there are multiple classes `ILogger` is being injected into?  For example, in one class it might have to inject a `Logger<MyClass>` object, in a second class a `Logger<SecondClass>` object.  It looks like Simple Injector can do that.  Can Unity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a name for each `ILogger` instance and use the `[Dependency]` attribute to specify which one you want. Example:

```
public static class Constants
{
    public const string LOGGER_MYCLASS_UNITY_KEY = "ILogger<MyClass>";
}
```

In your Unity registration:

```
IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterType<ILogger, Logger<MyClass>>(Constants.LOGGER_MYCLASS_UNITY_KEY, 
  new ContainerControllerLifetimeManager());
```

In the constructor of the class that needs the logger:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private readonly ILogger<MyClass> _logger;

    public MyClass([Dependency(Constants.LOGGER_MYCLASS_UNITY_KEY)] ILogger logger)
    {
        _logger = (ILogger<MyClass>)logger;
    }
}
```

HTH.

Comment: Thanks howcheng.  I was hoping to avoid having to register each individual Logger instance.  However, your answer would allow me to use `ILogger` parameters in my class constructors, rather than `ILogger<T>`.

Comment: Well, each `ILogger<T>` still has to be registered into the container, but you won't need to create concrete `ILogger<MyClass2>` etc classes at least.