# How to pass Microsoft Extenstion logger from ConfigureServices of Start up class to a static extension method in .NET 6

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-6.0

This is my code in .NET 6. If I do this I am getting this error

> Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger`1[xxx]' while attempting to activate 'xxx.Startup'.

How to fix this issue?

```
using Serilog;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
         Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).UseSerilog().
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            }).Build().Run();
    }
}

--------

using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;  

public class Startup
{
    public IConfiguration Configuration;
    public ILogger<Startup> _logger;

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, ILogger<Startup> logger)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
    {
        ExtensionMethod(_logger) // pass logger to static extension method here
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuider app )
    {
        staticextensionmethod(_logger)// pass logger middleware which is static
    }
}
```

Static method:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;  

public static class ExtensionMethodClass
{
    public static IActionResult ExtensionMethod(this ActionContext actionContext, ILogger logger)
    {
        logger.Info("");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change :

```
public ILogger>Startup> _logger;
      public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, ILogger>Startup> logger)
      {
         Configuration = configuration;
          _logger = logger;
      }
```

into:

```
public ILogger<Startup> _logger;
      public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, ILogger<Startup> logger)
      {
         Configuration = configuration;
          _logger = logger;
      }
```

Comment: Sorry that was  a typo when  I posted here.

Comment: @Jen  Have you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52921966/unable-to-resolve-ilogger-from-microsoft-extensions-logging  ?

Comment: @Jen  How about to create a logger, ILogger<ExtensionMethodClass> like: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#create-logs   And a litle strange, your program.cs is not like .net 6.   Have a look at [Logging from static members with Microsoft.Extensions.Logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46483019/logging-from-static-members-with-microsoft-extensions-logging)

Comment: thank you for sharing this link.Does it mean that it is not achievable? I am quite confused how to achieve it in my code

Comment: Also for static extension method ILogger<Extension MethodClass> is not supported