# Simple Injector: RegisterConditional with log4net

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, log4net, simple-injector

I'm trying to get log4net to work with Simple Injector by following the advice from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25113659/6570582) answer.
However, it appears that LogImpl now requires a constructor with an ILogger as a parameter:

> There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'logger' of 'LogImpl.LogImpl(ILogger)'.

[image]

Is there anyone that uses another method to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a breaking change in the `LogImpl` class. You can change your `Log4NetAdapter<T>` class to the following:

```
public sealed class Log4NetAdapter<T> : LogImpl
{
    public Log4NetAdapter() : base(LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(T)).Logger) { }
}
```