# How to enable Common.Logging.Log4Net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, log4net, common.logging

I am trying to enable Common.Logging.Log4Net to write all types of logs to a log file. The tutorials make it look so simple but I don't know what I am doing wrong. These are the steps I am taking:

1. Create a new ASP.NET MVC empty project
2. Install the "Common Logging Log4Net 1211" NuGet package
3. Add the following lines to the default web.config:

   ```
   <common>
       <logging>
           <factoryAdapter type="Common.Logging.Log4Net.Log4NetLoggerFactoryAdapter, Common.Logging.Log4Net">
               <arg key="configType" value="INLINE" />
           </factoryAdapter>
       </logging>
   </common>

   <log4net>
       <root>
           <level value="ALL" />
           <appender-ref ref="FileAppender" />
       </root>
       <appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender" >
           <param name="File" value="C:\Users\MyName\Downloads\log.txt" />
           <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
               <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline" />
           </layout>
       </appender>
   </log4net>
   ```
4. Make sure the app. pool identity account has RW access to the path where I am trying to save the log file.
5. Throw a random exception from code for testing purposes.

Am I missing anything? Is there a way I can debug log4net? Please help this poor soul. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

The issue was related to the NuGet package for "Common.Logging.Log4Net" changing the name of the assembly. This actually fixed it (plesae note the new assembly name, being `Common.Logging.Log4Net1211`):

```
<common>
    <logging>
        <factoryAdapter type="Common.Logging.Log4Net.Log4NetLoggerFactoryAdapter, Common.Logging.Log4Net1211">
            <arg key="configType" value="INLINE" />
        </factoryAdapter>
    </logging>
</common>
```

Comment: Hat tip to Common.Logging.Log4Net.Universal nuget package - does the same thing but independent of Log4Net version   <factoryAdapter type="Common.Logging.Log4Net.Universal.Log4NetFactoryAdapter, Common.Logging.Log4Net.Universal" />

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/756241/3469201

```
<configuration>
   <appSettings>
      <add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="true"/>
   </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Then, to determine the file in which you want to save the output you can add the following code in the same .config file:

```
<configuration>
...

<system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true">
        <listeners>
            <add 
                name="textWriterTraceListener" 
                type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" 
                initializeData="C:\tmp\log4net.txt" />
        </listeners>
    </trace>
</system.diagnostics>

...
</configuration>
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not familiar with Common.Logging.Log4Net. Here is the simple log4net steps that I use -

1. Install log4net from [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/log4net/).
2. Insert the following settings in web.config *(you can configure the way you want)*
3. Then log.

If you want to use IoC container, you can read [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30056680/what-is-the-disadvantage-of-manually-registering-log4net-logger-instance-to-ilog) I asked last month.

### web.config

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>
  </configSections>
  <log4net>
    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG"/>
      <appender-ref ref="FileAppender"/>
    </root>
    <appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
        <file value="log-file.txt" />
        <appendToFile value="true" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
  </log4net>  
</configuration>
```

### Testing inside Global.asax.cs

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

        XmlConfigurator.Configure();
        // You can inject it to your code using IoC container.
        var logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(MvcApplication));
        logger.Debug("Test Debug.");
        logger.Error("Test Error.");
        logger.Fatal("Test Fatal.");
        logger.Info("Test Info.");
    }
}
```

### Result

```
2015-06-04 11:48:05,885 [1] DEBUG DemoLog4Net.MvcApplication [(null)] - Test Debug.
2015-06-04 11:48:05,921 [1] ERROR DemoLog4Net.MvcApplication [(null)] - Test Error.
2015-06-04 11:48:05,922 [1] FATAL DemoLog4Net.MvcApplication [(null)] - Test Fatal.
2015-06-04 11:48:05,922 [1] INFO  DemoLog4Net.MvcApplication [(null)] - Test Info.
```

Comment: This answer has no relation to the question - Common.Logging.