# Solving error - Unable to resolve service for type 'Serilog.ILogger'

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, serilog

I am trying to implement SeriLog in ASP.NET core application (.NET framework)

Below are steps I performed so far-

1) Added below references in Project.json

```json
"Serilog": "2.2.0",
"Serilog.Extensions.Logging": "1.2.0",
"Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile": "2.0.0",
"Serilog.Sinks.File": "3.0.0"
```

2) Added following lines to the constructor of your Startup class-

```c#
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
           .MinimumLevel.Debug()
           .WriteTo.RollingFile(Path.Combine(env.ContentRootPath, "log-{Date}.txt"))
           .CreateLogger();
```

3) Added following line to the configure method of your Startup class-

```c#
loggerFactory.AddSerilog();
```

4) Injecting the logger to HomeController like this-

```c#
ILogger logger;

    public HomeController(ILogger logger)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
    }
```

5) In About action, trying to log exception like this-

```c#
public IActionResult About()
    {
        ViewData["Message"] = "Your application description page.";

        try
        {
            throw new Exception("Serilog Testing");
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            this.logger.Error(ex.Message);
        }

        return View();
    }
```

On running my application, I am getting below error-

> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type
>   'Serilog.ILogger' while attempting to activate
>   'AspNetCore_SeriLog_trial1.Controllers.HomeController'.    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider
>   sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, Boolean isDefaultParameterRequired)
>   at lambda_method(Closure , IServiceProvider , Object[] )    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.TypeActivatorCache.CreateInstance[TInstance](IServiceProvider
>   serviceProvider, Type implementationType)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(ControllerContext
>   context)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.d__26.MoveNext()

Could anyone please help me on this? Any configuration missing for Serilog?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to register ILogger for injection in ASP.NET MVC 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30194919/how-to-register-ilogger-for-injection-in-asp-net-mvc-6)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Try to do following thing in your controller.

```c#
    ILogger<HomeController> logger = null;
    public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> _logger)
    {
        logger = _logger;
    }
```

Comment: I tried this but getting error - `Error CS0308 The non-generic type 'ILogger' cannot be used with type arguments`

Comment: Are you using seri ilogger interface then try to replace it with Microsoft ilogger interface that present in logging library.

Answer (score 45):

If you need to use `ILogger` (from `Serilog`) instead of `ILogger<HomeController>` (from `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging`), you can register `ILogger` on your Startup class:

```cs
services.AddSingleton(Log.Logger);
```

Comment: I used this. Tnx!

Comment: Worked perfectly! Ty so much!!

Comment: Helped me to understand that `ILogger<HomeController>` will work, even though the docs didn't make it clear.

Answer (score 15):

Which of the following two lines do you have in your controller?

```
using Serilog;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
```

If it's the former (`using Serilog;`) then that's probably your problem.

When you register the service, you're essentially saying "When a constructor asks for an Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger, pass them a Serilog instance because I'm using Serilog for my logging", but then in your constructor **you aren't asking for Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger**, you're asking for **Serilog.ILogger** and your application is getting confused, because you haven't defined an service to be injected for `Serilog.ILoger`, you've defined one for `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger`

Remember that you are implementing Microsoft's ILogger interface: your constructor doesn't need to know that you're using Serilog... in fact, you don't want it to! The entire point is that you can swap Serilog out for a different logger at any time without having to change your code.

Change `using Serilog;` to `using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;` in your constructor, and you'll be requesting the correct service type

Answer (score 0):

You missed to inject your interface in the controller constructor:

```c#
ILogger<HomeController> logger = null;

public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> _logger)
{
    logger = _logger;
}
```

In the Program.cs you have to add UseSerilog also:

```c#
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .UseSerilog();
```

Answer (score 0):

My(!) Simplest solution for NET7.0 using the recommended *Host.CreateApplicationBuilder(args);* [MS Learn: Worker services in .Net](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/workers?pivots=dotnet-7-0)

NuGetPackages:

- Serilog
- Serilog.Extensions.Hosting
- Serilog.Sinks.Console
- Serilog.Sinks.File

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                   .MinimumLevel.Debug()
                   .WriteTo.Console(LogEventLevel.Information)
                   .WriteTo.File(path:"logs/Dummylog-.txt",rollingInterval:RollingInterval.Day)
                   .CreateLogger();
    
    
                var builder = Host.CreateApplicationBuilder(args);
                var services = builder.Services;
                builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
    
                services.AddSerilog(Log.Logger)
                        .AddHostedService<Worker>();
                      
                IHost host = builder.Build();
                host.Run();
            }
```

in the Service i injected the Serilog(!).ILogger *MS also has a ILogger interface, i could just write a using , but was lazy*

```
    private readonly Serilog.ILogger _logger;
    
            public Worker(Serilog.ILogger logger)
            {
                _logger = logger;
            }
    
            protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
            {
                while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    _logger.Information("Worker running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);
                    await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

I was getting this issue "unable to resolve service for type 'interface_name' while attempting to activate 'Controller_Name' ....

By adding the below line in startup.cs I have resolved the same:

```
services.AddScoped<interface_name, Controller_Name>();
```

Answer (score -1):

I know this is an old Question, but I just ran into this problem and found a different solution.

I switched out `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging` for `Serilog`, but I missed removing it from the constructor parameter list.

```
public HomeController(IIdentityServerInteractionService interaction, IWebHostEnvironment environment, ILogger logger)
```

Once I removed that parameter, the error disappeared.

```
public HomeController(IIdentityServerInteractionService interaction, IWebHostEnvironment environment)
```

It looks like the OP was trying to inject the logger through the constructor, but instead should have created a specific logger for that controller. You can also make it `static` so [there's only 1 creation of the logger for every time this project runs, instead of 1 for every instance of the class.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9410742/1836461)

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private static readonly ILogger Logger = Log.ForContext<HomeController>();
    ...

    public HomeController(IIdentityServerInteractionService interaction, IWebHostEnvironment environment)
    {
    ...
    }

    ...
}
```

Apparently, what's happening is that the compiler tries to give the constructor a `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging` logger by default, instead of trying to match the `Serilog` logger the constructor is actually expecting, so that's where the error comes from.