# Serilog MVC integration

Tags: asp.net-mvc, serilog

I have a project that utilizes a 3rd party software which uses Serilog. For that purpose I added the following to my Startup method in Startup.cs file.

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Verbose()
            .ReadFrom.ConfigurationSection(Configuration.GetSection("Logging:Serilog"))
        .CreateLogger();
```

On a separate project, I have service layer that uses a logging mechanism based on Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger.

Now I am adding UI to my initial project and I am injecting Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger to my controller classes through Service Collection; which I will then use (inside controllers) to create service layer objects.

The challange is; I would like to inject the existing Serilog logger into these controllers. Couldn't find a neat way of adding it to my service collection so that the controllers can fetch through DI. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to register an instance of your already-existing Logger object in your Dependency Injection container. Then this single instance will be passed to the constructor of your controller, instead of a new instance being created each time.

The code to do this will depend on the specific Dependency Injection framework you are using, but in Unity, it would be

```
   container.RegisterInstance<ILogger>(Log.Logger)
```

This should go after the code you posted, in which you instantiate `Log.Logger`.

You can additionally make your code more reusable by defining your own `ILogger` interface, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5646876/752601), so that your controllers are not tied to the `Serilog.ILogger` interface.