# Configure Simple Injector to support resolving ASP.NET Core middleware dependencies?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, simple-injector, asp.net-core-middleware

How can I configure SimpleInjector to resolve LogMiddleware's Invoke method dependency, like IMessageService ?

As I know, Asp.net core uses HttpContext.RequestServices (IServiceProvider) to resolve dependencies, I set SimpleInjector container to HttpContext.RequestServices property but didn't work. I want to change ServiceProvider dynamically because each tenant should have a container.

```
public class LogMiddleware
{
    RequestDelegate next;
    private readonly ILogger log;

    public LogMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        this.next = next;
        this.log = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<LogMiddleware>();
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context, IMessageService messageService)
    {
         await context.Response.WriteAsync(
                messageService.Format(context.Request.Host.Value));
    }
}

public interface IMessageService
{
    string Format(string message);
}

public class DefaultMessageService : IMessageService
{
  public string Format(string message)
  {
    return "Path:" + message;
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand exactly what your problem is. What prevents you from using your middleware?

Comment: How can I resolve middleware's dependencies from simple injector?

Answer (score 3):

You can use your `LogMiddleware` class as follows:

```
applicationBuilder.Use(async (context, next) => {
    var middleware = new LogMiddleware(
        request => next(),
        applicationBuilder.ApplicationServices.GetService<ILoggerFactory>());

    await middleware.Invoke(context, container.GetInstance<IMessageService>());
});
```

I however advise you to change your middleware class a little bit. Move the runtime data (the `next()` delegate) out of the constructor (since [components should not require runtime data during construction](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=99)), and move the `IMessageService` dependency into the constructor. And replace the `ILoggerFactory` with a `ILogger` dependency, since an injection constructor should [do no more than store its incoming dependencies](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/03/InjectionConstructorsshouldbesimple/) (or replace `ILogger` with [your own application-specific logger abstraction instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5646876/264697)).

Your middleware class will then look as follows:

```
public sealed class LogMiddleware
{
    private readonly IMessageService messageService;
    private readonly ILogger log;

    public LogMiddleware(IMessageService messageService, ILogger log) {
        this.messageService = messageService;
        this.log = log;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context, Func<Task> next) {
        await context.Response.WriteAsync(
            messageService.Format(context.Request.Host.Value));

        await next();
    }
}
```

This allows you to use your middleware as follows:

```
var factory = applicationBuilder.ApplicationServices.GetService<ILoggerFactory>();

applicationBuilder.Use(async (context, next) => {
    var middleware = new LogMiddleware(
        container.GetInstance<IMessageService>(),
        factory.CreateLogger<LogMiddleware>());

    await middleware.Invoke(context, next);
});
```

Or in case you registered the `ILogger` (or your custom logging abstraction) in Simple Injector, you can do the following:

```
applicationBuilder.Use(async (context, next) => {
    var middleware = container.GetInstance<LogMiddleware>();
    await middleware.Invoke(context, next);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is two problem with your code.

1. Your "DefaultMessageService" does not implement interface "IMessageService".
   It should be like this.

> ```
>  public class DefaultMessageService : IMessageService
>  {
>  public string Format(string message)
> {
>    return "Path:" + message;
>  }
> }
> ```

2. You have to register DefaultMessageService in ConfigureService in Startup.cs.

> ```
>  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
>         {
>             // Add framework services.
>             services.AddMvc();
>             services.AddSingleton<IMessageService>(new DefaultMessageService());
>         }
> ```

Comment: sorry I forgot to write IMessageService when creating question.