# How do I validate that a method argument is a valid enum using CuttingEdge.Conditions

Tags: c#, .net, validation, enums, serilog

In the SO post [Implementation and usage of logger wrapper for Serilog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5646820/logger-wrapper-best-practice/5646876#5646876), the author, [Steven](https://stackoverflow.com/users/264697/steven), shows a reference to a fluent method called IsValidEnum() as part of the Requires precondition (from the CuttingEdge.Conditions library, I assume). However, I cannot find that method in the v1.2.0 Nuget package. Is this a custom extension of the library? Is there a newer version of CuttingEdge.Conditions that I have not found. I would like to use this validation. Can anyone point me to the relevant library or provide a code snip?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you ask Steven himself in the comments of that post?

Comment: Could be [this one](https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/blob/43b21b0c1a02c838e570f3bf8a050f89b95a1dec/src/SimpleInjector/Requires.cs#L361)

Comment: @stuartd - I was assuming that the Requires was part of Stevens CuttingEdge.Conditions library but it is actually a class in the SimpleInjector library. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: @rory.ap - I didn't post a comment on the original post by Steven because I was not sure if older posts would get a timely response.

Comment: @EiEiGuy -- The author will get notified immediately.