# Simple Injector container can't resolve dependency

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, simple-injector

When `Verify()` my container I get the following error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in SimpleInjector.dll
>
> Additional information: The configuration is invalid. Creating the
>   instance for type ICommunicationApiFacade failed. The constructor of
>   type CommunicationApiFacade contains the parameter with name
>   'getLogger' and type `Func<Object, ILogger>` that is not registered.
>   Please ensure `Func<Object, ILogger>` is registered, or change the
>   constructor of CommunicationApiFacade.

This is my **IocConfig** class

```
container.RegisterSingleton<Func<object, ILogger>>(
    x => LogManager.GetLogger(x.GetType().FullName));

container.RegisterSingleton<Func<string, ICommunicationClient>>(
    tenant => new CommunicationClient(
        new Uri(configuration.AppSettings["communication_api." + tenant]),
        new TenantClientConfiguration(tenant)));

container.RegisterSingleton<ICommunicationApiFacade, CommunicationApiFacade>();
```

This is my **CommunicationApiFacade** class

```
internal class CommunicationApiFacade : ICommunicationApiFacade
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    private readonly Func<string, ICommunicationClient> _communicationFactory;

    public CommunicationApiFacade(Func<object, ILogger> getLogger,
        Func<string, ICommunicationClient> communicationFactory)
    {
        _logger = getLogger(this);
        _communicationFactory = communicationFactory;
    }
    ...
}
```

Interestingly, this logger is being used in other places. By removing any appearance of ILogger from CommunicationApiFacade all works fine.

Comment: I copy-pasted your configuration to a Console application, but everything works. Could it be that the `ILogger` abstraction that `CommunicationApiFacade` refers to is a different type than the `ILogger` that your Composition Root refers to? These things usually happen when mixing Common.Logging and log4net.

Comment: Prevent injecting a factory for the creation of loggers completely. This is leads to needed complexity and the only reason this is done is to implement context based injection. Please take a look at [Context based injection](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html#context-based-injection) section of the documentation.

Comment: You can let Simple Injector report fully qualified type names to make it easier to find these errors. Just set: `container.Options.UseFullyQualifiedTypeNames = true`.

Comment: That is correct @Steven the referenced abstraction was wrong in `CommunicationApiFacade`, after fixing the imports all worked fine, thanks.

Comment: Concerning loggers, also take a look at [the following advise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5646820/logger-wrapper-best-practice).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copy-pasted your configuration to a Console application, but everything works. Could it be that the `ILogger` abstraction that `CommunicationApiFacade` refers to is a different type than the `ILogger` that your Composition Root refers to? These things usually happen when mixing Common.Logging and log4net.